# Why isn't cell resizing when content is taller than the EstimatedSize (sizeHint)

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, reactiveui

I ported a table view implementation from Swift with a variable height cell. But in my Xamarin/ReactiveUI implementation, the cell does not resize when the content grows (i.e. when an optional label is displayed). Please note that the cell *does* resize to fit in the native Swift implementation.

Most answers online focus on the setting of two properties on `UITableView`: `RowHeight` and `EstimatedHeight` as well as using AutoLayout. My row height is set to `UITableView.AutomaticDimension` and the `EstimatedHeight` is set to `44f`. I am using autolayout constraints which I will show below. I am using the `BindTo` extensions in `ReactiveTableViewSourceExtensions`.

I also tried setting the `Text` property of the optional label right away to test the theory that setting the property up front would provoke a resize.

Here are the pertinent lines of code:
In a `ReactiveViewController<T>` ctor:

```cs
this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
{
    //// ...

    // This method automatically wires up the cell reuse key to be the nameof my cell class which is what I want.
    this.WhenAnyValue(view => view._cells)
        .BindTo<IImportedFileViewModel, ImportedFileCell>(TableView, 44f)
        .DisposeWith(disposables);
    //// ...
});
```

Below in `ViewDidLoad`:

```cs
//// ...

TableView = new UITableView
{
    RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension,
    EstimatedRowHeight = 44f, // Setting or not setting this doesn't matter
    SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None,
    AllowsSelection = false,
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
};

//// ...
```

In the cell implementation:

```cs
ClipsToBounds = true;
PreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true;
ContentView.ClipsToBounds = true;
ContentView.PreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true;

var stackView = new UIStackView
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical,
    Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill,
    Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Fill,
    Spacing = 4,
};

var fileStackView = new UIStackView
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
    Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill,
    Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Top,
};

FilenameLabel = new UILabel
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(15f, UIFontWeight.Medium),
};

fileStackView.AddArrangedSubview(FilenameLabel);

StatusImage = new UIImageView()
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center,
};

fileStackView.AddArrangedSubview(StatusImage);
stackView.AddArrangedSubview(fileStackView);

var reasonStackView = new UIStackView
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
    Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill,
    Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Top,
};

// This is the optional label that, when its Text property is set, should resize the cell.
FailureReasonLabel = new UILabel
{
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(13f, UIFontWeight.Medium),
    Lines = 0,
};

reasonStackView.AddArrangedSubview(FailureReasonLabel);
stackView.AddArrangedSubview(reasonStackView);
ContentView.AddSubview(stackView);

stackView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.LayoutMarginsGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
stackView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.LayoutMarginsGuide.TopAnchor).Active = true;
stackView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.LayoutMarginsGuide.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
stackView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(ContentView.LayoutMarginsGuide.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;

StatusImage.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(16f).Active = true;
StatusImage.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(16f).Active = true;
```

I would be happy to get a solution to the problem using the basic structure I have now *but* I would also accept an example of some other pattern that someone has used (based on ReactiveUI) to get this working. I would prefer that the solution not be based on old manual resizing patterns like in the pre-iOS 8 days or some sort of hack.

Comment: Where is the autolayout constraints of FailureReasonLabel?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT The FailureReasonLabel has its `Lines` property set to 0 (which should allow for unbounded wrap) and its parent stack view `Distribution` property is set to `Fill`, as is the `Distribution` property of its parent's parent.

Comment: No, I think you have to add the autolayout constraints to FailureReasonLabel, reasonStackView. Have a look at this thread as an example:  [how-to-resize-the-row-height-of-a-uitableview-automatically-in-xamarin-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830434/how-to-resize-the-row-height-of-a-uitableview-automatically-in-xamarin-ios)

Answer (score 0):

So two things had to be adjusted to fix my issue.

1. The `sizeHint` parameter in the ReactiveUI `BindTo` method does not behave like `TableView.EstimatedRowHeight`, which is what I was assuming. So I ended up setting it to the auto dimension constant like this:

```
.BindTo<IImportedFileViewModel, ImportedFileCell>(TableView, (float)UITableView.AutomaticDimension)
```

2. I was thinking that I could just update the properties of the view models within the `IObservableCollection` implementation that is passed in to the `BindTo` method but it wasn't until I started provoking changed events *on the collection itself* (the collection that the view is bound to) that the cells started resizing themselves. So since I am using DynamicData as part of ReactiveUI, that meant calling `SourceCache.AddOrUpdate(updatedViewModel)` whenever I knew that the `FailureReasonLabel` had been set.

I am also going to try and restore the `ReactiveUI` tag that was removed from this post because I believe it to be a relevant part of this question and its answer.